# Implementing TCF 2.2 if site uses Google Tag Manager rather than gtag.js

Tags: google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I need to implement Google Transparency Consent Framework (TCF 2.2) on a website that uses Google Tag Manager rather than gtag(). The [Google instructions for implementing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8YjX.jpg) state the window property (['gtag_enable_tcf_support']=true) must be set before any calls to gtag () are made. Where do I put the code if there is no gtag() code on the page? Do I put it before the Google Tag Manager code, will that work, too?